# JBoss 5.1 shows "Failed to process changes" when hot-deploying a WAR

Tags: java, jsp, jboss, war

I'm very new to this, so there's a good chance I'm doing something wrong, but I'm just trying to get set up with writing some JSPs using JBoss 5.1. I write the JSP page (really basic, just some HTML and a little bit of output to make sure the JSP is actually being processed) then I try to build the WAR and hot deploy it with the following commands:

```
jar -cvf jsptests.war *.jsp WEB-INF
copy jsptests.war "%JBOSS_HOME%\server\default\deploy"
```

If I do this without having JBoss running, then it will copy into the deploy folder and it will appear after I start JBoss, however, if I do the same thing while JBoss is running I see the following error in the console:

```
WARN  [org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner] (HDScanner) Failed to process changes
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while adding re-deployments
```

I've seen a few others experiencing this on some other forums but haven't found an answer anywhere. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This happends when the file is not fully copied, but JBoss's hot deploy scanner sees a .war file there and tries to read it.One way to do solve this is to move/rename the file rather than copy it as that operation is atomic on most operating systems (i.e. JBoss will not be able to "see" it until the operation is finished and thus it will not read an uncomplete file)

Comment: Also, it seems to work sometimes but the resulting page doesn't reflect my changes when viewed in the browser.

Comment: That usually means that the hotdeploy didn't work. WHat I recommend doing is leave the heavy JBoss AS for production deployment, and just use a lighter, faster app server for hot-deployment during development, like jetty. Jetty can easily be configured to pick up your code changes as you type them, so you can see the modifs immediately (GWT uses it just like that).